# Executing Perl Scripts Within Variables in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Following my professors exact instructions, I am trying to create a variable named EGG that contains 100 'A's by running this command from my Kali VM:

```
root@kali:~# EGG='perl -e "print 'A'x100"'
```

This is my result when attempting to echo the variable:

```
root@kali:~# echo $EGG
perl -e "print Ax100"
```

In my professor's demonstration, his variable contained 100 'A's as is expected.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: you can also show your professor this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 on why `$()` is preferred over ``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use back ticks in the shell to capture a command's output.

```
# EGG=`perl -e "print 'A'x100"`
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I was mistaking them for apostrophes on the replay of my professor's lecture.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that `$( )` (e.g. `EGG=$(perl -e "print 'A'x100")`) is preferred over backquotes -- it's much harder to misread.